# Using kubectl roll outs to update my images, but need to also keep my deployment object in version control

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

In My CICD, I am:

generating a new image with a unique tag. foo:dev-1339 and pushing it to my image repo (ECR).
Then I am using a rolling update to update my deployment.

`kubectl rolling-update frontend --image=foo:dev-1339`

But I have a conflict here.

What if I also need to update some part of my deployment object as stored in a deployment.yaml file. Lets say harden a health check or add a parameter?

Then when I re `apply` my deployment object as a whole it will not be in sync with the current replica set, the tag will get reverted and I will lose that image update as it exists in the cluster.

How do I avoid this race condition?

Comment: It is an interesing question but the answer is a bit complex :)

Comment: never counted on it being simple :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical solution here is to use a templating layer like [Helm](https://helm.sh/) or [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io).

In Helm, you'd keep your Kubernetes YAML specifications in a directory structure called a *chart*, but with optional templating.  You can specify things like

```
image: myname/myapp:{{ .Values.tag | default "latest" }}
```

and then deploy the chart with

```
helm install myapp --name myapp --set tag=20191211.01
```

Helm keeps track of these values (in Secret objects in the cluster) so they don't get tracked in source control.  You could check in a YAML-format file with settings and use `helm install -f` to reference that file instead.

In Kustomize, your CI tool would need to create a `kustomize.yaml` file for per-deployment settings, but then could [set](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/docs/plugins/builtins.md#field-name-images)

```
images:
  - name: myname/myapp
    newTag: 20191211.01
```

If you trust your CI tool to commit to source control then it can check this modified file in as part of its deployment sequence.

Answer (score 1):

### Imperative vs Declarative workflow

There is two fundamental ways of using `kubectl` for applying changes to your cluster. The **Imperative** way, when you do *commands* is a good way for experimentation and development environment. `kubectl rolling-updated` is an example of an *imperative command*. See [Managing Kubernetes using Imperative Commands](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/imperative-command/).

For a production environment, it is recommended to use a **Declarative** workflow, by editing manifest-files, store them in a Git-repository. Automatically start a CICD work when you *commit* or *merge*. `kubectl apply -f <file>` or more interesting `kubectl apply -k <file>` is an example of this workflow. See [Declarative Management using Config files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/declarative-config/) or more interesting [Declarative Management using Kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/)

### CICD for building image and deployment

**Building an artifact** from source code, including a container image may be done in a CICD pipeline. **Managing application config and applying** it to the Kubernetes cluster may also be done in a CICD pipeline. You may want to automatize it all, e.g. for doing *Continuous Deployment* and combine both pipelines to a single long pipeline. This is a more complicated setup and there is no single answer on how to do it. When the build-parts is done, it may trigger an update of the **image** field in the *app configuration repository* to trigger the configuration-pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no solution, either from the command line or through the yaml files

Answer (score 0):

As per the [doc here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/rolling-update-replication-controller/), "...a Deployment is a higher-level controller that automates rolling updates of applications declaratively, and therefore is recommended" over the use of Replication Controllers and `kubectl rolling-update`. [Updating](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) the image of a Deployment will trigger Deployment's rollout.

An approach could be to update the Deployment configuration yaml (or json) under version control in the source repo and `apply` the changed Deployment configuration from the version control to the cluster.